# Forced close on android from menu click? Log attached

Tags: android, logging, nullpointerexception, android-activity

So I put this project aside a few weeks ago and it worked perfectly. I made a few changes to one of the activities earlier today, loaded it into the emulator, and it died after getting to my menu screen (splash --> menu --> new activities). So after two crashes, I tried a different activity. One worked. Back... clicked another that hasn't been touched, boom. Force close/crash. I haven't changed anything in the menu java or XML file, nor the manifest.

What in the world could be causing this? There are no errors in Eclipse and I haven't changed anything, I thought, to cause it to do this.

log attached:

---

```
08-14 14:34:45.301: W/KeyCharacterMap(343): No keyboard for id 0
08-14 14:34:45.301: W/KeyCharacterMap(343): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
08-14 14:35:40.461: D/AndroidRuntime(343): Shutting down VM
08-14 14:35:40.471: W/dalvikvm(343): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
08-14 14:35:40.491: E/AndroidRuntime(343): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-14 14:35:40.491: E/AndroidRuntime(343): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.tomcat.performance/com.tomcat.performance.TireTemps}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-14 14:35:40.491: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
08-14 14:35:40.491: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
08-14 14:35:40.491: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
08-14 14:35:40.491: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
08-14 14:35:40.491: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-14 14:35:40.491: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-14 14:35:40.491: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-14 14:35:40.491: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-14 14:35:40.491: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-14 14:35:40.491: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
08-14 14:35:40.491: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
08-14 14:35:40.491: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-14 14:35:40.491: E/AndroidRuntime(343): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-14 14:35:40.491: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1637)
08-14 14:35:40.491: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at com.tomcat.performance.TireTemps.<init>(TireTemps.java:25)
08-14 14:35:40.491: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
08-14 14:35:40.491: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1429)
08-14 14:35:40.491: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
08-14 14:35:40.491: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
08-14 14:35:40.491: E/AndroidRuntime(343):  ... 11 more
```

---

TIRETEMPS.JAVA

```
package com.tomcat.performance;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
package com.tomcat.performance;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class TireTemps extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    EditText tempLFouterString = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.tempLFouter)),
            tempLFmiddleString = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.tempLFmiddle)),
            tempLFinnerString = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.tempLFinner)),
            tempRFinnerString = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.tempRFinner)),
            tempRFmiddleString = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.tempRFmiddle)),
            tempRFouterString = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.tempRFouter)),
            tempRRinnerString = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.tempRRinner)),
            tempRRmiddleString = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.tempRRmiddle)),
            tempRRouterString = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.tempRRouter)),
            tempLRouterString = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.tempLRouter)),
            tempLRmiddleString = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.tempLRmiddle)),
            tempLRinnerString = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.tempLRinner));

    TextView tempNoseAverageString = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.tempNoseAverage)),
            tempLFaverageString = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.tempLFaverage)),
            tempRFaverageString = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.tempRFaverage)),
            tempLRaverageString = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.tempLRaverage)),
            tempRRaverageString = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.tempRRaverage)),
            tempRearAverageString = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.tempRearAverage)),
            tempRFLRaverageString = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.tempRFLRaverage)),
            tempLFRRaverageString = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.tempLFRRaverage)),
            tempRSaverageString = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.tempRSaverage)),
            tempLSaverageString = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.tempLSaverage));

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tiretemps);

        Button calculate = ((Button) findViewById(R.id.calculate));
        calculate.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                double tempLFouter, tempLFmiddle, tempLFinner, tempRFinner, tempRFmiddle, 
                       tempRFouter, tempLRouter, tempLRmiddle, tempLRinner, tempRRinner, 
                       tempRRmiddle, tempRRouter, tempNoseAverage, tempLFaverage, tempRFaverage, 
                       tempLRaverage, tempRRaverage, tempRearAverage, tempRFLRaverage, tempLFRRaverage, 
                       tempLSaverage, tempRSaverage;

                try {
                    tempLFouter = Double.parseDouble(tempLFouterString.getText().toString());
                    tempLFinner = Double.parseDouble(tempLFinnerString.getText().toString());
                    tempLFmiddle = Double.parseDouble(tempLFmiddleString.getText().toString());
                    tempRFouter = Double.parseDouble(tempRFouterString.getText().toString());
                    tempRFmiddle = Double.parseDouble(tempRFmiddleString.getText().toString());
                    tempRFinner = Double.parseDouble(tempRFinnerString.getText().toString());
                    tempRRouter = Double.parseDouble(tempRRouterString.getText().toString());
                    tempRRmiddle = Double.parseDouble(tempRRmiddleString.getText().toString());
                    tempRRinner = Double.parseDouble(tempRRinnerString.getText().toString());
                    tempLRouter = Double.parseDouble(tempLRouterString.getText().toString());
                    tempLRmiddle = Double.parseDouble(tempLRmiddleString.getText().toString());
                    tempLRinner = Double.parseDouble(tempLRinnerString.getText().toString());

                    tempLFaverage = ((tempLFinner + tempLFmiddle + tempLFouter) / 3);
                    tempRFaverage = ((tempRFinner + tempRFmiddle + tempRFouter) / 3);
                    tempLRaverage = ((tempLRinner + tempLRmiddle + tempLRouter) / 3);
                    tempRRaverage = ((tempRRinner + tempRRmiddle + tempRRouter) / 3);
                    tempNoseAverage = ((tempLFaverage + tempRFaverage) / 2);
                    tempRearAverage = ((tempLRaverage + tempRRaverage) / 2);
                    tempRFLRaverage = ((tempRFaverage + tempLRaverage) / 2);
                    tempLFRRaverage = ((tempLFaverage + tempRRaverage) / 2);
                    tempLSaverage = ((tempLFaverage + tempLRaverage) / 2);
                    tempRSaverage = ((tempRFaverage + tempRRaverage) / 2);

                    tempNoseAverageString.setText(String.valueOf(String.format("%.1f", tempNoseAverage)) + "°");
                    tempLFaverageString.setText(String.valueOf(String.format("%.1f", tempLFaverage)) + "°");
                    tempRFaverageString.setText(String.valueOf(String.format("%.1f", tempRFaverage)) + "°");
                    tempLRaverageString.setText(String.valueOf(String.format("%.1f", tempLRaverage)) + "°");
                    tempRRaverageString.setText(String.valueOf(String.format("%.1f", tempRRaverage)) + "°");
                    tempRearAverageString.setText(String.valueOf(String.format("%.1f", tempRearAverage)) + "°");
                    tempRFLRaverageString.setText(String.valueOf(String.format("%.1f", tempRFLRaverage)) + "°");
                    tempLFRRaverageString.setText(String.valueOf(String.format("%.1f", tempLFRRaverage)) + "°");
                    tempLSaverageString.setText(String.valueOf(String.format("%.1f", tempLSaverage)) + "°");
                    tempRSaverageString.setText(String.valueOf(String.format("%.1f", tempRSaverage)) + "°");

                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    Toast andEggs = Toast
                            .makeText(TireTemps.this,
                             "Please verify only numbers are used in your inputs with no blank data.",
                             Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    andEggs.show();
                } catch (NullPointerException n) {
                    Toast andEggs = Toast.makeText(TireTemps.this, "Please enter all temperature data for each tire.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    andEggs.show();
                }
            }
        });

        Button reset_temps = ((Button) findViewById(R.id.reset_temps));
        reset_temps.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                tempLFouterString.setText("");
                tempLFinnerString.setText("");
                tempLFmiddleString.setText("");
                tempRFouterString.setText("");
                tempRFmiddleString.setText("");
                tempRFinnerString.setText("");
                tempRRouterString.setText("");
                tempRRmiddleString.setText("");
                tempRRinnerString.setText("");
                tempLRouterString.setText("");
                tempLRmiddleString.setText("");
                tempLRinnerString.setText("");

                tempNoseAverageString.setText("");
                tempLFaverageString.setText("");
                tempRFaverageString.setText("");
                tempLRaverageString.setText("");
                tempRRaverageString.setText("");
                tempRearAverageString.setText("");
                tempRFLRaverageString.setText("");
                tempLFRRaverageString.setText("");
                tempLSaverageString.setText("");
                tempRSaverageString.setText("");

                Toast andEggs = Toast.makeText(TireTemps.this, "All data has been reset.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                andEggs.show();

            }
        });
    }

    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

EDIT: Added TireTemps.java

Comment: Post TireTemps.java:25 and surrounding code.

Comment: I think you are trying to refer a null variable in TireTemps.java class (in and around the line 25)

Comment: I presume you cleaned the project?

Comment: Edited by adding TireTemps.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

findviewbyid works only after you have done a setContentView. But you are instantiating all the EditTexts at class instantiation itself. There is no way that findviewbyid will know where to look for the ids.

Move all the findviewbyid that you have done in field instantiation to Oncreate.

Comment: When moving them inside onCreate, I get major errors about referring to final/non-final variables. Is there a way to refer back to those variables later in the java with relative ease? Still a noob at this, so trying to learn on the fly :)  The odd part is it worked perfectly fine up until recently. Have a working version on my phone now before I added some edits.... none of which are popping up errors in eclipse.

Comment: declare the variables as field and then initialize them in Oncreate

Comment: Dunno why it worked before... but it did. Anyway, got everything re-initialized inside onCreate and don't seem to have a problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Tiretemps.java line 25 is accessing a variable that hasn't been instantiated or is null upon accessing it.

This can be based on how you declare variables, where you don't set them to a value at all, or in your other lifecycle functions they are cleared, such as `onPause` or `onResume`

Comment: The odd part about this, CQM, is this section of the app worked perfect the last time I was working with it. I hadn't edited or otherwise touched the file, now this. That's why I'm baffled. This particular part was where I wanted it and had no further planned edits.

Comment: try cleaning your project and run .